# Pattern matching first subdirectory in webkitRelative

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically, I want to pattern match the first directory folders or files.

How do I pattern match all the strings that are between two or "/". For ex.

I have this list :

```
Folder 1/File 2.avi
Folder 1/Folder2/File.avi
Folder 1/Folder2/Fils.mfg
Folder 1/Folder2/Folder 3/flag.gif
```

Of this list, I want the output to be,

```
Folder 1/File 2.avi
Folder 1/Folder2/
```

I just started with javascript regex and was lost. My try was very bad

```
str.match(/\/[abc]\//)
```

Thank you,
JJ

Comment: And what do you plan to do with this output?

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant to the question.I'll pass it into a php form. Im making a webpage, if its sufficient :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Matching the paths with regex**

The way they are in your file, you can use this (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lL9wI9)):

```
^[^/]*/[^/\r\n]*/?
```

The above regex will match `Folder 1/Folder2/` three times, so when you iterate through the matches, you only want to add the ones that are not in the array already.

**2. Only add the matched path if it is not already in the result array**

In code, you can add your matches to an array. See the [online demo](http://js.do/code/39613).

```
<script>
var subject = 'Folder 1/File 2.avi \n \
Folder 1/Folder2/File.avi \n \
Folder 1/Folder2/Fils.mfg \n \
Folder 1/Folder2/Folder 3/flag.gif';
var unikmatches = []; // we will build this
var regex = /^[^\/]*\/[^\/\r\n]*\/?/mg;
var match = regex.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // only add if it is not yet in unikmatches
    if(unikmatches.indexOf(match[0]) < 0 ) { 
        unikmatches.push(match[0]);
        document.write(match[0],"<br>");
        }
    match = regex.exec(subject);
}
</script>
```

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
[^/]*                    # any character except: '/' (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
/                        # '/'
[^/\r\n]*                # any character except: '/', '\r' (carriage
                         # return), '\n' (newline) (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
/?                       # '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                         # possible))
```

Comment: Hello, won't this give "Folder 1/Folder2/" twice? :)

Comment: @user3739937 Okay, added working code, and online demo of the working code. :) Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: How do i make the modification such that I select just Folder.avi and Folder 2 as my output removing all trailing slashed and the previous subdirectory? An if possible can you reason your regex. Havn't udnerstood that :(

Comment: Hey, glad it works. Added an explanation. For the other thing you're asking, that's a completely different regex (really), and comments are not a good place for that... Please ask a new question.

Comment: @user3739937 It's a pleasure, and if you ask the other question, leave a comment here and  I'll answer right away... On second thought I can do it without making it hugely different but there's potential for getting lost with more questions in the comments...